# Kusto Join Query - How to join 2 tables on $left.column1 < $right.column2

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have 2 tables in Kusto:

1. windowScans - each row is from this format : windowStart:long, windowEnd:long
2. files - each row is from this format: timestamp:long, fileId:string

I would like to join for each file all the windowScan rows that matches: timestamp > windowStart && timestamp < windowEnd.
The result should be a table of all files, and for each file all the matching pairs of windowScans.
It is possible that a windowScan row will appear in many files.
Any idea how to perform the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
let windowsScan = datatable(windowStart:long, windowEnd:long)[1,5, 6,8, 10, 14];
let files = datatable(timestamp:long, fileId:string)[3,"a", 4,"b", 4,"c", 6, "a", 11,"a", 13, "b"];
windowsScan
| extend timestamp = range(windowStart, windowEnd, 1)
| mv-expand timestamp to typeof(long)
| join kind=inner (files) on timestamp
| summarize take_any(windowStart, windowEnd) by fileId, timestamp
```

Results:

| fileId | timestamp | windowStart | windowEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| b | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| c | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| a | 6 | 6 | 8 |
| a | 11 | 10 | 14 |
| b | 13 | 10 | 14 |